# How to FIX ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency

Tags: java, android, firebase

After I updated com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads dependency from 17.1.2 to 18.2.0 I get error below :
After I updated com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads dependency from 17.1.2 to 18.2.0 I get error below :

After I updated com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads dependency from 17.1.2 to 18.2.0 I get error below :

```
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.0.
5]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:16.0.6 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-m
easurement-base@[16.0.5], but play-services-measurement-base version was 17.0.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@17.1.2
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics@16.0.6
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ads@17.1.2
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@18.2.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.6

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

its my build.gradle file Code . please help me to resolve it

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pkrcash.new19"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

// Maven Repositories
repositories {

    google()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }

}

dependencies {
    // Other Libraries
    api project(':library')
    // test Libraries
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Android Support Libraries
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    // Adnetwork Libraries
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.10.1'
    // MultiDex Dependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
    // slider library
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    // Google Libraries
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    // OLD implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation project(':spinlibrary')
    implementation 'com.byteshaft.requests:requests:0.5.3'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation project(path: ':androidscratchcard')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file

Comment: @PeterHaddad Code shared